# Did Google remove rating stars from SERP?

Tags: google-search, search-results, rich-snippets, schema.org

I read a few articles about it via Google and one or two questions on Stack Overflow (did not find them again, otherwise I would have linked them here) that say Google removed star ratings on SERP and only allows special verified rating systems to appear in SERP.

But now I found this on a SERP:

[image: Google Search results for the search 'google analytics checkout trichter', showing a Rating Rich Snippet for the second result from treefish.de]

And when I visit [this page](http://www.treefish.de/blog/conversion-optimierung-mit-google-analytics), I just see that they faked it. There is no rating feature and as a whole they just used two scopes, one for website and one for this rating aggregation:

> [image: Screenshot of the page’s footer, showing a sentence with the average rating]

So why is this working and other sites, with real rating features do not work?

Comment: There have also been cases where ratings disappeared from the SERPs and then returned again later as a result of the updates that Google has been making lately. Sometimes it is a month or so or even just a few weeks. Just keep that in mind. I am not sure of the exact conditions of this, however, it has panicked a few people here and there only to show up again. The cases I looked at all had valid mark-up.

Answer (score 1):

Google still documents the [Aggregate Ratings Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews#aggregate_ratings), and examples like the one you mentioned and others ([IMDb example](https://www.google.com/search?q=IMDb+2001%3A+A+Space+Odyssey)) prove that this snippet still gets displayed in Google Search.

In the case of the mentioned page’s use of Microdata and Schema.org: They provide a `WebSite` item with an `aggregateRating` property. So the `AggregateRating` item is for the aggregate ratings *of the website*, not of the page or the blog post. But for whatever reason they only include this item in their blog. (Side note: they provide a `description` property for `ẀebSite` which is different for each page; which is not correct.)

The fact that Google Search shows the Rating Rich Snippet for all of the site’s blog posts is strange, because the second [guideline](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews#review-specific_usage_guidelines_and_policies) doesn’t seem to be fulfilled:

> Make sure the reviews and ratings you mark up are readily available to users from the marked-up page. It should be immediately obvious to users that the page has review or ratings content.

and because the site clearly marks up (i.e., following the first guideline) that the ratings are not for the blog post but for the whole site, so Google Search should have no reason to display that rating for each blog post (this gives the wrong impression that the blog posts would be rated).